# Flutter screenshots for Frameit

Tags: android, flutter, fastlane, frameit

I am automatically generating screenshots of my Flutter app during integration testing and using Fastlane Frameit to put them in a frame and make them all pretty. This works perfectly well with the iOS version. But for Android I am having issues. The bounds of the Flutter screen do not include the bottom navigation bar.

[image: Flutter screenshot]

Frameit requires the image size to be 1080x1920 or whatever the device resolution is, but running on a device of that size only yields an image 1080x1857. The extra room is for the navigation bar. Further, the screenshot does not include the status bar at the top, but it's the size that's the major issue because it prevents Frameit from running at all.

Surely this is an issue that people have run into before. How has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to modify image dimensions online you can use these websites :

https://www.iloveimg.com/resize-image#resize-options,pixels

https://www.img2go.com/resize-image

I used them to resize screenshots to upload to google play and apple store

Comment: Two issues with this. 1) I want to do this as part of a CI/CD pipeline to remove human involvement, and 2) just resizing the image would distort the screenshot.